# Dynamic validation based on conditions

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-form-validation

**Scenario:** I have 4 form fields.

1. Description (Optional)
2. Select Type (Required)
3. Phone (Required only if Select Type is set to 'Phone')
4. Email (Required only if Select Type is set to 'Email')

When I change anything is Select Type field, based on the selection, Phone field or Email field will be visible. I need to validate these fields.

**Problem:**

When the form loads, it'll have only description, select type dropdown and save button.

Step 1: Click save button without entering any input, should throw an alert saying `Select Type is required` and select type will be red.

Step 2: Select a type, the next input becomes visible with red border. This should not happen since the user didn't touched the field. How can I solve this?

**Code:**

[Stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rnj-angular-form-validation-example)

**html**

```
<div class="example-container">
    <form [formGroup]="groupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <section>
            <section class="input-row">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput type="test" placeholder="Description" id="description" formControlName="description"/>
        </mat-form-field>
            </section>
            <section class="input-row">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-select id="sourceType" formControlName="sourceType" placeholder="Select Type*">
                        <mat-option value="phone">Phone</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="email">Email</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </section>
            <section *ngIf="typeIsPhone" class="input-row">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput type="number" placeholder="Phone" id="phoneValue" formControlName="phoneValue"/>
        </mat-form-field>
            </section>
            <section *ngIf="typeIsEmail" class="input-row">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput type="email" placeholder="Email" id="emailValue" formControlName="emailValue"/>
        </mat-form-field>
            </section>
        </section>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" class="save">
      Save
    </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**component:**

```
export class FormFieldOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  typeIsPhone = false;
  typeIsEmail = false;
  public groupForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    description: new FormControl(""),
    sourceType: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    phoneValue: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    emailValue: new FormControl("", [Validators.required])
  });

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.groupForm
      .get("sourceType")
      .valueChanges.subscribe(this.setSourceType.bind(this));
  }

  setSourceType(SourceType: string) {
    this.typeIsPhone = SourceType === "phone";
    this.typeIsEmail = SourceType === "email";
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const sourceTypeFormControl = this.groupForm.get("sourceType");
    const phoneEnteredFormControl = this.groupForm.get("phoneValue");
    const emailEnteredFormControl = this.groupForm.get("emailValue");

    if (sourceTypeFormControl.errors.required) {
      alert("Source Type is required!");
      return;
    } else {
      if (phoneEnteredFormControl.errors.required) {
        alert("Phone is required!");
        return;
      }
      if (emailEnteredFormControl.errors.required) {
        alert("email is required!");
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can check whether user changed `formControl` value with its `pristine` property

Comment: I tried using `markaspristine` and `markasuntouched`. still the field is showing as red

Comment: Just check whether formControl is `pristine` and show error if it is and is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As if a FormControl is disabled don't has errors I suggest another aproach using disable and enable that you can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rnj-angular-form-validation-example-aid5ny?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const control=this.groupForm.get("sourceType")
    if (control)
       control.valueChanges.pipe( //Use startWith to execute at first
             startWith(control.value)
       ).subscribe(res=>this.setSourceType(res)); //<--see how pass the value
  }

  setSourceType(SourceType: string) {
    this.typeIsPhone = SourceType === "phone";
    this.typeIsEmail = SourceType === "email";
    const phoneControl=this.groupForm.get('phoneValue')
    const emailControl=this.groupForm.get('emailValue')
    if (phoneControl) 
      phoneControl[SourceType==='phone'?'enable':'disable']() //(*)
    if (emailControl)
      emailControl[SourceType==='email'?'enable':'disable']()
  }
  //(*) is a abreviated way to say 
  //             if (SourceType=='phone')
  //                phoneControl.enable()
  //             else
  //                phoneControl.disable()
```

NOTE:

```
  //You can not use 
  if (phoneEnteredFormControl.errors.required) //WRONG
  //use 
  if (phoneEnteredFormControl.errors && phoneEnteredFormControl.errors.required) //OK
```

Comment: I should not disable the save button. any error should be reported after hitting the save button.

Comment: then, remove `[disabled]="groupForm.invalid"` from button , it was only an example

Comment: But still I'm getting that red border without touching phone formcontrol

Comment: well if you get out the button from the form, I think work according your requeriments. I updated the stackblitz

Comment: Now I'm not even getting the reb border if the field is invalid. First clicking save button without any type gives me an error alert and the source type will be red. Then If i select Phone, the phone form element will be visible, now the phone also has red border. I wish to remove that red border, because the user didn't touched that element.

Comment: Ranjith, if you get off the form the submit button, when submit, not mark as touched the controls, so you need make it manually (again update stackblitz)

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the submitted property, the button with implied type=submit, and the way the default ErrorStateMatcher handles this [case](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/8050f633b56b6c048fc72dad2ab79304afdfad19/src/lib/core/error/error-options.ts#L24).

Maybe use

```
type="button" (click)="onSubmit()"
```

Comment: I tried that, in this case. The alert is triggering but the red border is not applied even if the formcontrol is invalid